# How should I apply Ambient Occlusion from greyscale AO maps?

Tags: shading, ambient-occlusion

I've seen many tutorials on SSAO, but none for simple ambient occlusion maps.

I can see myself working things out alone, as AO maps are simple greyscale maps that indicate where there should be more lighting and where less, right? Something like

```
float ao = texture(ambientOcclusionMap, uvCoords);
vec3 lighting = ambient + (diffuse + specular) * ao;
```

Is there something more to it?

Comment: Instead of multiplying diffuse and specular terms with ao, you should multiply ambient term with ao.

Comment: Oh ok. That's the only thing to it though?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct approach is to multiply ambient component with AO:

```
vec3 lighting = ambient * ao + diffuse + specular;
```

** *it is not a coincidence, that both items have the the word "ambient" in them ;-)*

Comment: This is not exactly "correct" it's just a reasonable approximation of correct. Correct would involve computing a darkening factor for the diffuse term.

Comment: @MickLH This sounds reasonable. Can you post an equation for that?